# PC freezes and becomes unusable.It happens at random while I do simple tasks I have to turn it of and on again. I use Kubuntu 22.04.1 kernel 5.15.0-52

Tags: kernel, kubuntu, freeze

It happens randomly while browsing or exploring my files. I noticed that at the time it happens it uses 100% of my cpu. I've tried to clear cache with Stacer and I ran autoremove but this thing keeps happening. What can I do? Any help would be appreciated as it happens twice a day. Its unbearable.

Comment: *what* uses 100% of your CPU? can you check which program is using all that CPU time?

Comment: I cannot because when it reaches 100% it freezes instantly! Before that the usage its normal!

Answer (score 0):

I faced a system freeze issue the other day, after a fresh install (22.04 on external SSD). When it freezes, the SSD was burning hot, and I immediatly linked it the wierd partitioning behaviour that happened during installation (the first partition was preceeded with 33 mb unused space that cannot be reduced and it should be 1 mb). After enforcing the right partitioning layout using gparted separately and reinstalling ubuntu using the prepared layout, the system works absolutely great, and is very reliable.